# Comparing two large polynomials

Tags: polynomials

How would one show that $g(n) > h(n)$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z} : n \geq 2$

$g(n) = 2048n^{15} + 45568n^{13} +112768n^{11} +70624n^9 +11968n^7+674n^4+68n^2+1$
$h(n) = 14336n^{14} + 87296n^{12} +104064n^{10} +35184n^8 +1796n^6+764n^5+268n^3+11n$

I was originally going to say
since all the coefficients are positive, $\deg(g(n)) > \deg(h(n))$ and there exist $p \in \mathbb{R} : g(p) = h(p)$ then any $n>p$ will satisfy $g(n) > h(n)$

However I can't understand/grasp why any number greater than $p$ will satisfy $g(n) > h(n)$.

Comment: Both polynomials have positive coefficients only, this should be quite trivial. Do you need a formal proof?

Comment: Yes, I need a formal proof. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if $\ n\ge8\ $ then every term on the right side of the following equation is obviously positive:
\begin{align}
g(n)-h(n)&=n^{14}(2048n-14336)+n^{12}(45568n-77296)\\
&\hspace{2em}+n^{10}(112768n-104064)+n^8(70624n-35184)\\
&\hspace{2em}+n^5(11968n^2-1796n-764)+n^3(674n-268)\\
&\hspace{2em}+n(68n-11)+1\ .
\end{align}
For $\ n=7\ $ the first term in the sum on the right side is zero, but all the other terms are positive.
Therefore, to show that the expression is positive for all integers $\ n\ge 2\ $, you simply have to check that it's positive for the $5$ integers $\ n=2,3,4,5,6\ $.